# How to set row selection after releasing the mouse left click?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a `datagridview`. In this `gridview` when I left click and hold on the line and drag and drop it down to another line it is working fine but the selection of row remain same.

eg. If I select row# 2 and drag it to row# 4 , row# 2 drop at position 4 but row selection remain same. I want that when I drop it to row# 4 selected row should be row# 4.

I have done some code for drag and drop functionality.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // If the mouse moves outside the rectangle, start the drag.
        if (dragBoxFromMouseDown != Rectangle.Empty &&
            !dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y))
        {

            // Proceed with the drag and drop, passing in the list item.                    
            DragDropEffects dropEffect = dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown],
            DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    rowIndexFromMouseDown = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
if (rowIndexFromMouseDown != -1)
    {           
        Size dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;
        dragBoxFromMouseDown = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X - (dragSize.Width / 2),
                                                       e.Y - (dragSize.Height / 2)),
                            dragSize);
    }
    else
        // Reset the rectangle if the mouse is not over an item in the ListBox.
        dragBoxFromMouseDown = Rectangle.Empty;
}

private void dataGridView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    // Get the row index of the item the mouse is below. 
    rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop =
        dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).RowIndex;

    // If the drag operation was a move then remove and insert the row.
    if (e.Effect== DragDropEffects.Move)
    {
        DataGridViewRow rowToMove = e.Data.GetData(
            typeof(DataGridViewRow)) as DataGridViewRow;
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndexFromMouseDown);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop, rowToMove);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the lines

```
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown].Selected = false;
```

at the end of `dataGridView1_DragDrop` so that the selection will change. you have changed the rows problematically, and that means that the selection of the `dataGridView` did not changed with it.

Comment: While "problematically" is likely more accurate, I'm guessing you meant "programmatically"

Comment: @Cyborgx372 indeed i did :)

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop].Selected = true;

Comment: @AmitKumar what are you trying to say?

Comment: He's suggesting you use something like: rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex; Where e.X, e.Y are the coordinates taken from: private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)